# How to catch fabric exception at Application class ? #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, crashlytics

I used Fabric in many project using

```
Fabric.with(this, Crashlytics())
```

but i got many crash speciality on android 8.1

`java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6476)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1969)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:109)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7377)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:469)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:963)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:419)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.getSharedPreferences (ContextImpl.java:404)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences (ContextWrapper.java:167)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.persistence.PreferenceStoreImpl.<init> (PreferenceStoreImpl.java:39)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.AdvertisingInfoProvider.<init> (AdvertisingInfoProvider.java:37)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.IdManager.<init> (IdManager.java:114)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric$Builder.build (Fabric.java:262)
  at io.fabric.sdk.android.Fabric.with (Fabric.java:313)
  at kdev.prayertimes.PrayerApplication.onCreate (PrayerApplication.java:14)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1123)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap2 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1969)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:109)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7377)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:469)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:963)`

How to solve this problem ? why fabric cause app crashed in startup of app ?

## AskFirebase

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. What version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using firebase-core:16.0.3 with crashlytics:2.9.4
compileSdk 27

Comment: Try updating to 2.9.5 and let me know if that fixes the issue for you.

Comment: thanks for your response, i will try it